# Multiple definition error in C

Tags: c

Why am I getting multiple definition error here? After all I am using `i` in two separate files.

```
//file1.c
#include <stdio.h>
#include "foo.h"
int i=700;
int main() {
    printf("in main i is %d\n", i);
    foo();
}

//file2.c
#include <stdio.h>
int i =800;
void foo() {
printf("in foo i is %d\n", i);

}
```

Error:

```
$ gcc file1.c file2.c
/tmp/ccyRgnlM.o:(.data+0x0): multiple definition of `i'
/tmp/ccoTZsnQ.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I was reading the GNU C reference Manual: http://www.gnu.org/software/gnu-c-manual/gnu-c-manual.html#Scope

and I quote from there: "Unless explicitly stated otherwise, declarations made at the top-level of a file (i.e., not within a function) are visible to the entire file, including from within functions, but are not visible outside of the file."

Comment: You have two *globals* called `i`, so it shouldn't be too surprising that you get link errors - you could just make them `static`.

Comment: "After all I am using i in two separate files" -- uh, two is multiple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The statement about "visibility" you quoted is formally correct, but requires precise understanding. In particular, you have to understand the difference between *declarations* and *definitions*, as well as the difference between being "visible" for *name lookup* purposes or for *linkage* purposes.

The statement you quoted specifically talks about properties of *declarations*. Indeed, a *declaration* made at the top level of the file is only visible within that file. "Visible" in this case means "visible for *name lookup purposes*".

However, your declarations if `i` are more than just declarations. They are *definitions* as well.

And since they are definitions, they also have to obey the rules that govern *definitions*, like "one-definition rule" of C language. The rule says that entities with external linkage  (variables or functions) have to be *defined* once and only once in the entire program. For *linkage* purposes entities with external linkage are always visible to the entire program.

A file-level variable declared without storage class specifier acquires external linkage by default, i.e. it becomes a *global* variable. Such variable still needs to be *redeclared* in each file where you want to use it (to make it *visible* in that file). However, you are not allowed to *redefine* it in any other translation unit.

If you really want to have an independent variable `i` in each translation unit, you have to make sure you declare it with *internal* linkage, i.e. with keyword `static`.

Comment: Thank you Andrey. Is there official documentation on external vs internal linkage? Can you point me to one. I am going to see GNU C documentation myself, but any reference would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You have two global variables called `i`, and they clash with each other.

Since they are two distinct variables, declared them as `static`. This will reduce their scope to the corresponding translation unit (i.e. source file).

For example:

```
static int i = 700;
```

Comment: Please see my addition to the post where I quoted from the GNU C reference manual.

Comment: @abc: They are not visible in the sense that `file1.c` can only see its own `i` and not the other one (and vice versa). The two `i`'s still clash with each other at link time.

Answer (score 2):

You are not only *using* but you are *defining* global variable `i`  in both `file1.c` & `file2.c`

<sup>Notice that in *C* a variable *declaration* is not the same as a *definition* !</sup>

You have

```
int i=700;
```

and

```
int i=800;
```

What initialization of global location `i`  do you want? It cannot be both 700 & 800 and it cannot be *defined* twice.

The correct way would be to have a header file `myheader.h`:

```
#ifndef HEADER_INCLUDED
#define HEADER_INCLUDED
extern int i;
void foo (void);
#endif
```

and add `#include "myheader.h"`  at start of each `file1.c`  and `file2.c`  to *declare* (not define) a global variable `i`  and define it in *one single file* (often the one containing `main`, here `file1.c`) :

```
 // file1.c
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include "myheader.h"
 int i=750;
 int main() {
   printf("in main i is %d\n", i);
   foo();
 }
```

You might want to have two different variables `i`  (but avoid doing that, this is **bad practice** for readability reasons), then declare `static int i;`  in each `file?.c`  and don't mention `i`  in the header file.

At last, as a beginner in C using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/), *always* compile *with all warnings and debug info* ie with at least `gcc -std=c99 -Wall -g`  (and improve your code till no warning happens). Learn how to use `make`  (the builder) and `gdb`  (the debugger).

Comment: Please see my addition to the post where I quoted from the GNU C reference manual.

Answer (score 1):

Fro global symbols, C uses flat namespace. That means, there cannot be the same global symbol in different files since their name will be the same and thus, multiple definition linking error occurs. The solution is to either rename so they're all unique, or limit the scope by prefixing the symbol with `static`, so the symbol is known locally to the file (better: translation unit) only.

P.S.: Symbol means identifier, it can be variable, function, type, etc.

Answer (score 0):

When you `#include` a file, cpp (the C pre-processor) literally pastes the lines of that file in place of the `#include` line, so when you think of it that way, it's obvious to see how `i` has been defined twice.

To do what you intended, i.e., to create two separate file-scoped variables called `i` (one for each source file), declare them `static`--this will give them file scope, and get rid of the warning.

```
/* file1.c */
static int i = 700;

/* file2.c */
#include "file1.c"
static int i = 800;
```